# Can anybody help me out with a html/css dropdown menu issue?

Tags: html, css, menu

I just started to create a website and all is perfect, without the menu...

My menu has some problems: the "top levels" are okay, but the "second levels"/dropdown menus are not good and I can't figure out how to fix them. They are not under "their parents" and the width and height of them are not good. I would like to see padding or a specific width for exemple 100px for all submenus and height 20px for all, but I can't get it to work.

### HTML

```
<div>
    <ul type="none">
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="nav" href="#">Home</a> 
            <ul class="dropdownitems">
                <li><a class="dropdownitem" href="#">Home Style1</a></li> 
                <li><a class="dropdownitem" href="#">Home Style2</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdownitem" href="#">Home Style3</a></li> 
                <li><a class="dropdownitem" href="#">Home Style4</a></li>               
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="nav" href="#">Other</a> 
            <ul class="dropdownitems">
                <li><a class="dropdownitem" href="#">Other1</a></li> 
                <li><a class="dropdownitem" href="#">Other2</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.nav {font-family: times new roman, arial, "ms sans serif", sans-serif; text-decoration: none; color:#484848; font-size:17px;}
.nav:visited { text-decoration: none; color:black;}
.nav:focus { text-decoration: none; color:black;}
.nav:hover, nav:active { text-decoration: none; color:black;}
.nav:hover {
font-family: times new roman, arial, "ms sans serif", sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
color: orangered;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: solid 3px orangered;
}

.dropdownitems {
display:none;
}

li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdownitems {
  display:block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  clear:both;
  width: 100px;
}


.dropdownitem { 
font-family: times new roman, arial; 
text-decoration: none; 
color:black; 
background-color:#F0F0F0;

}
.dropdownitem:visited { text-decoration: none; color:black;}
.dropdownitem:focus { text-decoration: none; color:black;}
.dropdownitem:hover, nav:active { text-decoration: none; color:black;}
.dropdownitem:hover {
font-family: times new roman, arial, "ms sans serif", sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: solid 3px orangered;

}

span div ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.dropdown
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width:60px;
}
```

Please take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/9afrX/1/

If you check it, you will see all the problems, if any body can correct it, please do it, I will really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: don't know.. but when I change in your CSS script the left: 0 value to lets say 50px. it is better alinged. you mean that ?

Comment: I added 50px as you said, but all is the same, just appears bullet points:|, after that I added 50 (without px) and now it is aligned, so thanks :) ,but how about the padding ?

Comment: I think umang is right. You moved the children elements <li> out of the text flow with position: absolute. so they positioned just left, the additional 50 just moved it 50 right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `position:absolute;` to the dropdown , you should make it parent `list(li)`

```
position:relative
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9afrX/13/

Comment: yes, it works :) Can you help me too with the padding/spacing problem ?

Comment: Please look at this picture. http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/css-menu/4.jpg The difference that my menu is "underlined" and coloring on hover + transparency, but on other hand I want that the submenus has space around text like on that image. I tried with paddin, margin, but are still the same.

Comment: please wait for while im doing it for you

Comment: Sure! And thanks :) Please note that I would like it to be underlined, on hover, just like to parent menu. I already added this, but it is not really visible, if you could correct this too, I would be very happy :) Thanks again :)

Comment: no problem just wait for while i will definately will send you in 15 min

Comment: Hmmm...not exactly, it is just better :)) Thanks! Can you give me your skype id, please ? :)

Comment: i think we can discuss here

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `position: absolute;` from your css block `li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdownitems`

Comment: Not required... You can have it or you can ignore that too. Depends on your requirements. Please dont forget to accept the answer if it works for you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, but I need a padding for the text from the submenu item, or space. How to do it ?